# Como saber se uma soma binária de unsigneds deu overflow?

Tags: assembly, binary

Se tenho uma soma de dois numeros unsigned (1 byte cada) num assembly sem carry flag, como posso saber se deu overflow?

Edit: a arquitetura em questão é a Neander

Solução: descobri um modo de fazer isso. Primeiro checa-se os bits mais significativos (msb) dos números a serem somados.

```html
Se ambos forem 1, teremos overflow.
Senão, se apenas um deles for 1 e o msb do resultado for 0, teremos overflow
```

Comment: Fica difícil sem saber a CPU.

Comment: Então, é a arquitetura Neander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução: descobri um modo de fazer isso. Primeiro checa-se os bits mais significativos (msb) dos números a serem somados.

Se ambos forem 1, teremos overflow.

Senão, se apenas um deles for 1 e o msb do resultado for 0, teremos overflow

Answer (score 1):

Os comandos `"JO"` (jump on overflow) ou `"JNO"` (jump on not overflow) possibilitam fazer esse teste e seguir conforme o caso.

Comment: É a arquitetura Neander, só há JZ, JNZ e JN. Eu precisaria implementar o carry em si

Answer (score 1):

Se a soma de dois números sem sinal resultar em um número menor que o menor número então um overflow ocorreu. 
Exemplo:

```
  1111  
+ 0001  
1 0000
```

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, mas como comparar os números sem recorrer a complemento de dois?

Comment: Fiquei pensando nisto ontem. Mas não achei nada.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no edit, @fabio

Comment: Verdade:
1111 + 1111 = 1 1110 (primeiro caso)
1111 + 0011 = 1 0010 (segundo caso)
O correto é você responder sua própria pergunta e não edita-la com a resposta.

Comment: Certo, farei isso